# Standard empty argument type functioning like void

Tags: c++, c++20

Is there a type in the standard that functions like `void`? i.e. something that is actually omitted from the argument list, like a tag-esque structure?

```
void foo(){}
void foo(std::empty_type){}
// assembly for these two should be the same, no arguments
```

My use case: I am writing my own range-based `for` iterator object. The issue is that the object returned is sufficient for checking if it's at the end (I am wrapping an API). This range-based `for` is hit a lot, and any minor optimizations will have a drastic increase on code performance. The thing is, I cannot declare a unary `operator !=` nor can I declare a symbol of type `void` as per the standard, so I'd like to emulate it with an object of size 0.

What type can I use to hint to the compiler to omit the argument altogether? Will something like `std::monostate` work? From my tests on MSVC, `using empty_type = struct {}` is not the solution.

Comment: There's no such thing in the C++ standard. You'll just have to hope that your compiler will optimize everything away, when an empty struct is involved.

Comment: That stinks. Is there a specific type I should favor for this to tell the reader what my objective is then?

Comment: A dummy `int` argument has been used since forever to distinguish between pre and post increment. So I would assume that spotting tag arguments is something compilers would have had enough time to get right, even when they are potentially stateful. You can write small test cases on https://godbolt.org/ to see how your compiler behaves.

Comment: If your hot loop is this important, you might have to ultimately make some sacrifices and restructure the code to be uglier for the sake of optimization. One thing that springs to mind since you're iterating over something is SIMD. If you can restructure to leverage SIMD in some way for at least part of your hot loop operations (even compiler-generated SIMD), that could potentially be a quite profitable venture. More generally, you could also consider parallelization like what OpenMP provides. Depending on the problem, such parallelization can provide significant speedup.

Comment: look up "tag dispatch"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what sentinels are for.

I'm assuming your iterator looks something like this:

```
struct iterator {
    // ... usual iterator interface ...

    // iterator knows when it's done
    bool is_done() const;
};
```

You can make your own sentinel type:

```
struct is_done_sentinel { };
```

Add the comparison between them (which in C++20 is just a single operator, in C++17 you have to write all four):

```
bool operator==(iterator const& lhs, is_done_sentinel ) {
    return lhs.is_done(); // adjust as appropriate for your actual iterator
}
```

And then have your range return this sentinel as its end:

```
struct range {
    iterator begin();
    is_done_sentinel end() { return {}; }
};
```

This will have the behavior your want: your range ends when the iterator is done, and there's no overhead on the check.

Answer (score 2):

> The issue is that the object returned is sufficient for checking if it's at the end (I am wrapping an API).

C++20 recognizes this as an "Iterator/Sentinel" range, which has replaced the traditional "Iterator/Iterator" model that requires the two Iterators to be the same type. C++17 was actually pre-emptively extended to support such a construct, as C++14 and before required that the `begin` and `end` iterators of a range-based `for` loop's range type be the same type. C++17 changed this to allow for different types.

A Sentinel is a type that acts like an end iterator without being an Iterator. Indeed, [the only real requirement of a Sentinel](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iterator.concept.sentinel) is that it is equality-testible with the Iterator it is paired with. Any iterator which tests equal to its sentinel is considered to be the end of the range.

Obviously another Iterator is a Sentinel. But the fact that a Sentinel doesn't have to be an Iterator is empowering.

If you have a Sentinel value that isn't an Iterator, odds are good that the Sentinel doesn't do anything. In most such cases, the Iterator happens to store all of the information needed to determine whether it is at the end. `istream_iterator` and similar stream-based iterators are examples of such, and they could have Sentinels (they don't, as they predate the Sentinel paradigm. Instead, an "end" iterator for such a range is a default-constructed iterator). So your `operator==` is just a way to call `Iterator.IsEnd()` or whatever function is needed.

> What type can I use to hint to the compiler to omit the argument altogether?

None. But that's fine, because you don't need to.

Let's look at where our Sentinel values will exist. In most cases where a Sentinel is just a means to trigger an `operator==` call, the Sentinel is monostate. It's a distinct type (which is *important*, because we don't want to have an istream Sentinel type being able to be used with a counting range or some other nonsense), but if it has a member function, it's just `operator==`.

That means that the range type doesn't need to store a Sentinel; it merely needs to have `end` produce one. So it returns a prvalue of a newly created Sentinel.

Since (complete) objects in C++ are required to take up storage, it will have a size of between 1 and 4 bytes. So worst case, there's a 4 byte object on the stack.

Next, range-`for` will invoke `operator==` on the Iterator/Sentinel pair. Well, there's basically no excuse for not making this function `inline`, and since all this function will do is call a function on the Iterator, there's no excuse for a compiler (with optimizations on) to not inline the function.

And once it's inline... the compiler can see that the Sentinel isn't doing anything. Since the function is inline, it won't be passed as a parameter. And it's not actually used by the inlined code; it's just sitting there.

Worst case, the compiler will leave a 4-byte object on the stack that isn't doing anything. But more than likely, the compiler will just get rid of it.

But if you don't want to take my word for it, I present to you `nul_terminator`, a Sentinel for `const char*` iterators that point to NUL-terminated strings. Naturally, the `operator==` dereferences the iterator and tests it against 0.

```
struct nul_terminator {};

//This code is C++17, since C++20 support is spotty, but you only need one of these in C++20.
bool operator==(const char *it, nul_terminator) {return *it == 0;}
bool operator==(nul_terminator, const char *it) {return *it == 0;}
bool operator!=(const char *it, nul_terminator) {return *it != 0;}
bool operator!=(nul_terminator, const char *it) {return *it != 0;}

class string_range
{
public:
    const char *begin() {return str_;}
    nul_terminator end() {return {};}

    string_range(const char *str) : str_(str) {}

private:
    const char *str_;
};

int manual_sum_values_of_string(const char *str)
{
    int accum = 0; //Just to give the function something to do, so the optimizer doesn't make it go away.
    for(; *str != 0; ++str)
        accum += *str;

    return accum;
}
int range_sum_values_of_string(string_range str)
{
    int accum = 0; //Just to give the function something to do, so the optimizer doesn't make it go away.
    for(auto ch : str)
        accum += ch;
    return accum;
}
```

If you [look at the assembly output from the three major compilers](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/xLyU3T) for `manual_sum_values_of_string` vs. `range_sum_values_of_string`, you'll find that they're virtually identical. And I don't mean "there's overhead, but you can ignore it". I mean "the same, except the order of a couple of non-dependent opcodes is swapped."

GCC produces equivalent results at optimization level 1, while Clang and MSVC require O2 before they get equal results.

Basically: don't worry about it. Compilers are smart, so let them do their jobs.

Comment: "because we don't want to have an istream Sentinel type being able to be used with a counting range or some other nonsense" - I'm not sure if you did this on purpose, but `std::default_sentinel_t` is indeed a sentinel for both `counted_iterator` and `istream_iterator`.

Comment: @Barry: I didn't know about that, so I didn't write it on purpose; I just picked an iterator that probably knew its own size. And yes, that type is some hot nonsense ;)

Comment: Yeah that's what I figured, pretty funny random choice of iterators :-D.